# Polar to linear movement of a yoke

Tags: math, trigonometry

I am writing an algorithm to convert a polar movement of a mechanical yoke (pan and tilt) and to a linear movement between 2 points.
i.e. I know the start and end pan & tilt values but want to ensure that the end result is a straight line and not an arc. 
To help picture this, the application is a light and the circle of light projected always wants to move in a straight line.

I have worked out that if tilt does not change between the start and end points then as the light pans across its arc the tilt needs to deflect down towards 0 half way through the movement and back to its original value again by the end of the movement. The tilt would do a V as the light pans.

The amount of maximum deflection is given by:

`DELTA = tilt_angle - ( tilt_angle x cos(half_angle_of_pan) )`

My question is what to do in the case of the end tilt being different to its start?
Would adding this DELTA to the changing value to tilt give the same end result or does the calculation get more complicated?

Martin

Comment: I find the question confusing, eg if the tilt does not change between start and end......the tilt needs to deflect down towards 0! How does knowing the start and end pan and tilt values give a start and end point for the straight line? What is the circle of light projected onto? Please add further details of the physical situation you are modelling.

Comment: Image that you have a laser on a yoke (pan and tilt). The yoke can move 360 degrees pan and +/- 90 degrees tilt.
The yoke is at 45deg tilt and 0deg pan and the instruction to move is for pan to go to 90deg over 5 seconds. The result is that the laser will track an arc from 0 to 90deg. However with linear movement I want the laser to move in a straight line between its start point and its end point (shortest path might be a better term).
This is relatively simple if the start and end tilt values remain unchanged. The question is what happens if the end point has a different tilt angle?

Comment: Sorry I must be being particularly dense today. If the yoke can only pan and tilt how can the laser move in a straight line? When you talk about the laser do you mean the tip of the physical laser from where the light is emitted? Any chance of a picture?

Comment: Here is an example of the lights I am talking about
http://www.vari-lite.com/vl-products/series3000/vl3000-spot/

Comment: I will try and add a diagram soon. But to answer your question the light can go in a straight line by adjusting tilt while pan moves. That's the point of the equation in the question.